# Can't grep command resultats in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Good Morning,

Context : 
I would like to check every minute if a python script is running. In my cron, i call a script. The script's goal is to check if the process is running.

My script :

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="path/to/directory"
CMD="python3 -u $DIR/script.py -arg1 $DIR/arg1 -arg2 $DIR/arg2 -arg3 $DIR/arg3"

if [ ! $(ps aux | grep 'my_pattern' | grep -v 'color')]
then
    echo "Success"
    "$CMD" > /dev/null
fi
```

With this script i want to grep the process and inverse the grep to exclude the color process. If the process is running, the command (ps aux | grep 'my_pattern' | grep -v 'color')returns me something if not, the command returns me nothing.

The error is ./script.sh: line 12: [!myuser+ : Untraceable command

The execution of the command did not returns me the result of the command but the process number of my command like if i did a ps aux of my command.

If it's not clear, please ask, difficult for me to translate the issue.

Thank you for answering.

EDIT : I HAVE APPLY the ocndition like this :

```
if [[ -z $(ps aux | grep 'my_pattern' | grep -v 'color') ]]
```

Now i don't have any errors but it never enter in my if condition.

Comment: You have a **typo**: `'color')]` should be `'color') ]`

Answer (score 0):

With

`if [[ -z $(ps aux | grep 'my_pattern' | grep -v 'color') ]]`

(mind the typo as shown by klashxx)

you can check if the variable is empty.

So instead of using "!", i think it's more appropriate and effective to check if the grepping of ps aux is returning an empty string or not.

Let me know if this helped you or not.

EDITED: corrected '[' to '[['

EDITED AGAIN: for other users to know, if u need to check the existance of a process with this method append `!` before -z flag to see if it is NOT empty

Comment: thanks for answering.
You're answer help me well, but i've a new issue (that's good).
./script.sh: line 12 : [: too much arguments

Comment: Don't worry, i've already try this after your answer.
Now i don't have any errors but it never enter in my if condition...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Remember that -z returns true (and enter the if) if the result is empty...so if u want to check if the process exists, u should check if -z flag is false...like ! -z

Comment: Ok thank you. Just feel stupid about the if condition.

It works.

Comment: no problem ;) glad to hear it worked :) Happy coding

Comment: My bad, it doesn't work. 
it never enter in my if condition. If i echo the results of the ps aux | grep | grep i have a results.
In command line it works, it returns me nothing but in shell script i have :
myuser+ 6061 0.0 0.1 14264 968 pts/11 S+ 14:35 0:00 grep mypattern

Comment: u should try adding grep -v 'grep' to correctly avoid displaying the grep process itself, let me know

Comment: No, that's the wrong fix for that problem. Use `pgrep` or if that's not available then `grep '[r]egexp'` instead of `grep 'regexp'`, i.e. put the first literal character of your regexp inside square brackets so `grep 'regexp'` doesn't match `[r]egexp` in the ps output.

Comment: didnt know that, thanks also from my side. Both working, but this is way more elegant and correct.